# cannot :destroy if last existing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, cancancan, ruby-on-rails-5.2

## The Setup

I'm using Rails 5.2 and [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan).

```
rails g scaffold Hotel name
rails g scaffold PriceGroup name hotel:references
```

**hotel.rb**

```
has_many :price_groups, dependent: :destroy
validates :price_groups, :presence => true
```

**ability.rb**

```
if user.admin?
  can :manage, :all
else
  can :read, :all
end
```

## The Challenge

I want to make sure that a `Hotel` always has at least one `PriceGroup`.

How can I configure cancancan to allow an admin to destroy a `PriceGroup` only if `self.hotel.price_groups.count > 1`?

I want to use CanCanCan tools to just display a delete button on the WebGUI when possible.

Comment: It's not really an answer, so I'll just comment: You should not place your business logic validation in the same place when you define abilities (SRP and stuff). You should put it as before_delete callback, or better yet use something like https://toptal.github.io/granite/ oro http://trailblazer.to/ and define your business logic there.

Comment: What is not working with `can :destroy, PriceGroup { |price_group| price_group.hotel.price_groups.count > 1 }`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What [@meta said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51765855/cannot-destroy-if-last-existing/51887207#comment90492330_51765855) is right, you shouldn't be adding your business logic to the ability . Instead you can override the existing `destroy` action in your `PriceGroup` model.

That makes your logic universal (meaning, even a code outside the CanCan cannot delete the last object).

An example would be

```
class PriceGroup < ApplicationRecord

  def destroyable?
    PriceGroup.where(hotel_id: hotel_id).count > 1
  end

  def destroy
    return super if destroyable?
    raise "You cant delete the last price group of hotel #{hotel_id}"
  end 
end
```

Of course you can make the code more prettier , but you get the idea :)

## update

Adding CanCan ability based on my above example

According to the document [here](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities-with-Blocks), you may try something like

```
can(:delete, PriceGroup) { |price_group| price_group.destroyable? }
```

Comment: But how to use CanCanCan to display a delete button in the view in that scenario? If it is possible to delete something the button should be displayed but not if it isn't.

Comment: @wintermeyer, I've updated my answer to use a cancan ability too :)

Comment: The problem was: "How can I configure cancancan to allow an admin to destroy a PriceGroup only if self.hotel.price_groups.count > 1?"

Comment: @wintermeyer The principal stays the same. I updated the answer to better include the context of the question (currently waiting for peer review).

Comment: thanks @JohanWentholt for the edit and improving the answer .

Comment: @wintermeyer, answer is now updated with Johan's changes :)